# What caused a hole in the motor of my Dodge ram 1500 5.7 V8 Hemi pickup?

Tags: dodge, ram, hemi

The gages have been perfect, oil was fine not overheating.

Out of blue the power died and smoke rolled out. Oil every place. Nothing else looks damaged, just a hole.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Do you have more information on the issue? Where did you find the hole in the engine? Do you have a picture of it? Did you notice anything unusual to the vehicle prior to the incident like sounds, vibrations or warning lights?

Answer (score 2):

Something bad happened.

While it's difficult to say without a teardown, the most common issue on most engines causing a catastrophic failure is an oiling problem.  Once there is an interruption in the oil supply the most common problem is seizure of the connecting rod big end.  This causes the rod to break and then as it thrashes around on the end of the crankshaft it often punches a hole in your engine block.  Hence the oil everywhere.

There are, of course, other possible problems like a piston seizing in the cylinder, a crankshaft main bearing failure, a broken piston, as well as a host of other problems.

It's also possible that this just happened on its own.  Perhaps there was a defect in the manufacturing of some part and it just let go at that moment.